# Computing $\int_0^2 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor\,dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Compute $\int_0^2 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor\,dx$.

The challenging part isn't the problem itself, but the notation around the x^2. I don't know what it is. If someone could clarify, that would be great!

Edit: Clarified that it represents the floor function, can anyone give me a hint on how to start working on the problem?

Comment: As the $\LaTeX$ suggests, that is the floor function which essentially means round down, for example $\lfloor 4.1\rfloor=4$

Comment: Its the floor function, the greatest integer smaller than the given number.

Comment: For future reference, http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: It may help if you try graphing it.  The integral is the area under the curve.  There isn't even any real calculus necessary to get the answer.

Comment: The floor function is a piecewise constant.  This should be near trivial to solve.  Note for $0 \le x < 1$ then $[x^2] = 0$.  for $1 \le x < \sqrt 2$ then $[x^2] = 1$ and for $\sqrt 2 \le x < \sqrt{3}$ then $[x^2] = 2$ and for $\sqrt 3 \le x < 2$ then $[x^2] = 3$.  So $\int_{0}^2  [x^2]dx = \int_{0}^1 0 dx + \int_{1}^{\sqrt 2} 1dx + \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt 3} 2 dx + \int_{\sqrt{3}}^2 3 dx$.

Answer (score 6):

The following diagram shows the effect that the greatest integer function has on the graph of $y=x^2$.
[image: Greatest integer function of x square]

The answer will equal the area of the three rectangles on the right. Note that the endpoints of the three intervals on the $x$ axis will be $1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},2$.

You should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 4):

That is the greatest integer, or floor, function.  The notation $\lfloor x \rfloor$ stands for the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.  Think of it as "rounding down" to the next integer.